# Foreach using two viewbag

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to do a foreach using two viewbag thus in the view, but I get an error in the second foreach.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.stages)
{ 
      <div id="style101">
         <h2><span> <strong>@item.NameStage</strong></span></h2>
      </div>
    foreach (var item2 in (ViewBag.actions.IdStage == item.IdStage ))
```

How I can do this?

Comment: What data are you passing in ViewBag. There should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

**Try to avoid using ViewBag / ViewData** to pass data from your action methods to view. You must have realized now that this made your view a bit dirty. **Use strongly typed view models.**

Assume your view is to create something. So create a view model for that. Assuming you have multiple Actions in each stage.

```
public class CreateSomeThingVM
{
  public string Title { set;get;}  
  public List<Stage> Stages { set;get;}

  public CreateSomeThingVM()
  {
    Stages=new List<Stage>();
  }
}
public class Stage
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string StageName { set;get;}
  public List<Action> Actions { set;get;}
  public Stage()
  {
    Actions =new List<Action>();
  }
}
public class Action
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string ActionName { set;get;}
}
```

And in your Action method, get the data and set the properties.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new CreateSomeThingVM();

  vm.Stages=GetListOfStagesFromSomeWhereWithItsActions();

  return View(vm);
}
```

Assumuing `GetListOfStagesFromSomeWhereWithItsActions` method returns a list of `Stage` object with its proper `Actions`.(You should do your filtering here as needed to get the relevant actions for each stage).

Now in your View which is strongly typed to our CreateSomeThingVM view model, write some clean code

```
@model CreateSomeThingVM

@foreach(var stage in Model.Stages)
{
  <h2>@stage.StageName</h2>
  foreach(var action in Model.Actions)
  {
    <p>@action.ActionName</p>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the expression in your second loop after the **in** keyword evaluates to a boolean rather than an IEnumerable.
Did you mean to use .where() to filter an enumerable instead?
Perhaps:

```
Viewbag.actions.where( a => a.IdStage == item.IdStage)
```

Comment: I get this error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: You will need to cast the actions property to the concrete type that it contains in order to use extensions off of IEnumerable.  ((kalusTypeForAction)Viewbag.action).where(...)